# the right syntax to use near 'PARTITIONS 101 */ AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 19

Tags: mysql, database, server

I am trying to import a large database to my local server with the help of Bigdump script (www.ozerov.de/bigdump/), but I get this error:

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `email_addon_rbp_hard_bounces` (
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`log_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`rcpt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`message` varchar(455) DEFAULT NULL,
`ip` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`job_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`cat_pmta` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`group` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`pattern` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`log_id`),
KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
PARTITIONS 101 */ AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

ERROR:

> MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'PARTITIONS 101 */ AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 19

What do I do to get past it and import the full db?

Comment: Remove the `PARTITIONS 101 */`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. I just searched for all "PARTITIONS 101 */" entries and deleted all the line beginning in /*, ending at the */, just before the semicolon.

Do not delete the semicolon.

Comment: There is no line beginning / here, or semicolon.